# Different icon looks when selecting different scaling

Tags: windows, icons

I need help setting default icons for my windows profile. Strange thing is that whenever I'm changing the scaling from 100% to 125% the icons are also changing looks.

What I want is the icons at 100% to stay the same whenever I'm changing the scaling of windows.

Here are the differences:

[100% scaling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgfGl.png)

[125% scaling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnQ0L.png)

Anyone know the solution to this issue?

Comment: Might I suggest you ask this question at http://superuser.com/?  Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I didn't know about superuser.com, will ask my question there